# Which type of service should I use for data migration?

Tags: android, android-service, scoped-storage

I need to migrate my app data in order to use Scoped Storage. I would like to do it in a service, so it's transparent for the user. The service will be launched when the user opens the app for first time after the update.

But I don't know which type of service would be best. A plain Service will be enough? Which limitations does it have? Do I need a foreground service? JobIntentService? WorkManager?

Answer (score 0):

Plain service that is a foreground service would probably be the best option but you could also use a one time WorkManager task since they can also start a foreground service

Comment: A foreground service requires showing a notification, a "plain" service does not. Will be enough using a "plain" service (without notification)? Or does it have any limitations?

Comment: If you have a lot of things to migrate then I would suggest against it, a normal service can/will get killed by the OS if the app is put into the background. Foreground service will only get killed under extreme circumstances

Comment: Thank you. I'll go with a foreground service.